# Parsing Bungie Clan Data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am able to parse json data from multiple sources with PHP, but cant seem to figure out the json data from Bungie, specifically clan members. I have spent hours Googling and attempting as array, as object, etc.

Below is a sample of the first 2 users (yes its public data). If any PHP json parse lords could help me with minimal sample working code Im sure I can run with it.

```
    {"Response":{"results":[{"memberType":2,"isOnline":false,"groupId":"913961","destinyUserInfo":{"iconPath":"/img/theme/destiny/icons/icon_xbl.png","membershipType":1,"membershipId":"4611686018442185846","displayName":"Gim Allon"},"bungieNetUserInfo":{"supplementalDisplayName":"Gim Allon","iconPath":"/img/profile/avatars/s_tbagjx8.gif","membershipType":254,"membershipId":"3025645","displayName":"Gim Allon"},"joinDate":"2016-06-18T23:05:59Z"},{"memberType":2,"isOnline":true,"groupId":"913961","destinyUserInfo":{"iconPath":"/img/theme/destiny/icons/icon_xbl.png","membershipType":1,"membershipId":"4611686018434168228","displayName":"speedyred8"},"bungieNetUserInfo":{"supplementalDisplayName":"7734728","iconPath":"/img/profile/avatars/bungie_day_15_26.jpg","membershipType":254,"membershipId":"7734728","displayName":"speedyred8"},"joinDate":"2017-05-15T01:06:17Z"},{"memberType":2,"isOnline":false,"groupId":"913961","destinyUserInfo":{"iconPath":"/img/theme/destiny/icons/icon_xbl.png","membershipType":1,"membershipId":"4611686018434232581","displayName":"Fall3N KnighT"},"bungieNetUserInfo":
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what have you tried?  Have you started with a `json_decode()`?

Comment: At this point Im just throwing everything at it (too much to list here):

$getUsers = json_decode($userList,true);
$userTag = $getUsers[0][Response]
$userTag = $getUsers['Response'][1]['memberType'];
$userTag = $getUsers['Response']['memberType'][1];
$userTag = $getUsers->Response->results;
$userTag = $getUsers->Response->{ results };

$getUsers = json_decode($userList);
$userTag = $getUsers{'Response'};
$userTag = $getUsers->Response;

Kind of works:
// return var_dump(json_encode($userList[0])); (Result: string(3) ""{"")

Comment: Finally got it figured out: ['Response']['results'][$x]['destinyUserInfo']['displayName'];